# I am trying to keep the plot output on the side of the settings bar but I can't seem to move it! Does anyone know how?

Tags: r, shiny

[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hShPc.png)

I have used the code below! People said add columns I tried that but it is not moving up or down. I can move it to side using offset argument but that is about it. I know I must be doing something wrong. this is the first time I am using shiny dashboard to build an app. normal one is not so difficult when it comes to formatting. I would like to use this package to learn how to polish the style of my app.

The goal is that the settings menu and plot come side by side.

```
side = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(width = 150,
    menuItem("Dimension-Plot", tabName = "Dimension-Plot"),
    menuItem("Violin-Plot", tabName = "Violin-Plot"),
    menuItem("Dot-Plot", tabName = "Dot-Plot"),
    menuItem("Feature-Plot", tabName = "Feature-Plot"),
    menuItem("Average-Expression", tabName = "Average-Expression"),
    menuItem("Differential-Expression", tabName = "Differential-Expression")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Dimension-Plot",
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 12, plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click", width = "100%", height = "300px")),
                column(10,
                       sidebarPanel(
                         selectInput("Dim1", h3("Settings"), 
                                     choices = list("True" = TRUE,
                                                    "False" = FALSE), selected = 1),
                         selectInput("Dim2", label = "Seperate Plots",
                                     choices = list("Null" = "Null",
                                                    "Sample" = "orig.ident",
                                                    "Condition" = "Type",
                                                    "Clusters" = "RNA_snn_res.1"), selected = 2),
                         selectInput("Dim3", label = "Group Plots",
                                     choices = list("Sample" = "orig.ident",
                                                    "Condition" = "Type",
                                                    "Clusters" = "RNA_snn_res.1"), selected = 3),
                         numericInput("Dim4", label = "Label Size", value = 4, min = 1, max = 20),
                         numericInput("Dim5", label = "Point Size", value = 4, min = 1, max = 20),
                         selectInput("Dim6", label = "Label Color",
                                     choices = list("Black" = "black",
                                                    "Blue" = "blue",
                                                    "Red" = "red"), selected = 1)
                       )
                )
              )
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Violin-Plot",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Dot-Plot",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Feature-Plot",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Average-Expression",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Differential-Expression",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    )
  ))


ui <- dashboardPage(header, side, body)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points; in a bootstrap fluidpage, there are no more and no less than 12 columns. therefore your attempted use of 10+12 wont work ... for 50/50 go with 6 + 6
at least as a start point, go to 5 + 7 if it works better for you , experiment, but they must add to 12.

Also in the default setup, what you put first, goes on the left. therefore putting the plot as the first thing, wont work to have it on the right. so swap the order around.

finally you use sidebarPanel without a sidebarLayout, that wont give good results.
Rather than add a sidebarLayout, I switched the sidebarPanel for an inputPanel.

here is your dimension tab as I have it

```
tabName = "Dimension-Plot",
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                column(6,
                       inputPanel(
                         selectInput("Dim1", h3("Settings"), 
                                     choices = list("True" = TRUE,
                                                    "False" = FALSE), selected = 1),
                         selectInput("Dim2", label = "Seperate Plots",
                                     choices = list("Null" = "Null",
                                                    "Sample" = "orig.ident",
                                                    "Condition" = "Type",
                                                    "Clusters" = "RNA_snn_res.1"), selected = 2),
                         selectInput("Dim3", label = "Group Plots",
                                     choices = list("Sample" = "orig.ident",
                                                    "Condition" = "Type",
                                                    "Clusters" = "RNA_snn_res.1"), selected = 3),
                         numericInput("Dim4", label = "Label Size", value = 4, min = 1, max = 20),
                         numericInput("Dim5", label = "Point Size", value = 4, min = 1, max = 20),
                         selectInput("Dim6", label = "Label Color",
                                     choices = list("Black" = "black",
                                                    "Blue" = "blue",
                                                    "Red" = "red"), selected = 1)
                       )
                ),
                column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click", width = "100%", height = "300px"))
              )
            )
```